# Perform Function Every Day (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, function

I n my iOS app, I have something like a quote of the day. How would I update the "quote" everyday. I have the quotes in a variable like

```
var quotes = ["The most amazing quote in the world", "This makes no sense"]
```

I would like to it to it in the `viewDidLoad`. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Everyday new content on Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090476/everyday-new-content-on-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways to do this, for example if we did a quote for every day of the month for example just make sure to have 31 quotes and you can use the day of the month to index into your array of quotes:

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dayOfMonth = calendar.component(.day, from: date)

quoteOfDay = quotes[dayOfMonth] // Make sure you have 31 quotes
```

---

**Update**: If you want more random you can use the `hashValue` then:

```
let date = Date()
let dateIndex = Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970) / (60*60*24)
let quoteOfDay = quotes[dateIndex % quotes.count]
```

Comment: Does it have to be exactly 31 or can it be more?

Comment: If you want it to be more then you'll need to decide how you want to handle it because there are max 31 days in a calendar month so it'll never index higher. If you want to index higher you could think of other ways to "index" such as taking the number of days since Unix start time and modulo the number of quotes you have thus you can index into it. Etc.

Comment: How about randomizing with `Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quotes.count)))`? How would I do that?

Comment: You can randomize but by doing so you don't get a "quote of the day", you get a "quote of the random generation" ... but sure if you like to do a random quote then that could work too. Otherwise if you want an index based on the day you can do something like `Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970) % 50` as your index (with 50 quotes)

Comment: Correct, that's what I mean by you'll get a "quote of the random generation", it's going to be different every time. So in order to get "quote of the day" you'll need to fix it based on the date such as `Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970) % 50` could be fixed and change day by day and assumes 50 quotes total. (Updaetd the answer to have more random but fixed on date to be based on `hashValue`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149412/discussion-between-jacob-cavin-and-richardhsu).

Comment: Just to clarify if anyone reads these comments, my bad but the above interval code isn't correct in that I forgot it returns the number of seconds since 1970. So in fact we'll need to transform it to number of days which is presented in the given answer.